# Injecting spring beans in non managed objects

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

the below bean of Class I want to inject in other non-managed bean, but it is not working as expected

```
@Component
@Setter
@Getter
public class AbstractLayoutProperties {
    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    @Autowired
    S3Service s3Service;

    @Autowired
    S3Client s3Client;

}
```

Below is the class which is not managed by the spring, but I am using `@Configurable`

```
        @Configurable(preConstruction = true, autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
        @EnableSpringConfigured
        public class OverlayServiceImpl
                implements GenericVehicleOverlayService<T, R> {
public findOnlyActive(){
appName = layoutProperties.getAppName(); // throwint NullPointerException beacuse the object not injected properly
}
    @Autowired
        AbstractLayoutProperties layoutProperties;
    }
```

One more point, `findOnlyActive` method I am not calling directly, I am calling this from another service, lets say

```
@Service
public class OtherService{

public void findActive(){
OverlayServiceImpl impl=new OverlayServiceImpl();
 impl.findOnlyActive();
}
@Autowired
OtherRepository otherRepo;
}
```

**Problem statrement:**

when `impl.findOnlyActive();` is executed, it should inject all the required beans inside `OverlayServiceImpl`. In the same class I have two beans which are autowired, it seems none of them injected, this is the reaosn that every time I am encountering Nullpointer exception. so my question is how do I make it work, what are the steps and action I need to take so that spring will inject the dependencies in non managed object i,e `OverlayServiceImpl`.

Comment: and ... do you have an actual question?

Comment: see my edits for the actual problem statement

Comment: the steps you need to take is: make sure that class is managed by Spring, otherwise the autowiring will not work. An alternative to autowiring is creating factories for your classesz

Comment: Could you please demonstrate the solution, it would be really helpful

Comment: To use `@Configurable` you will need to use loadtime or compile time weaving with AspectJ, else it won't work. If you haven't set that up (properly) then it won't work.

Comment: I have tried the setup, but the problem is Aspet J is not properly working with Lombok I am using 1.14.0 verison for AspectJ, also I have refer lot of post but that didn't help me to make Configurable work